# Appending a row of an ND numpy object array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I'm trying to create an ND numpy object array to store data of different row lengths, but whenever I try to append an array by directly indexing that row, every row gets appended.

```
myArr = np.empty(10, dtype=object)
myArr.fill([])
```

which gives

```
array([list([]), list([]), list([]), list([]), list([]), list([]),
       list([]), list([]), list([]), list([])], dtype=object)
```

but if I want to append, say, the 3rd row of this array by

```
myArr[2].append(1)
```

I get

```
array([list([1]), list([1]), list([1]), list([1]), list([1]), list([1]),
       list([1]), list([1]), list([1]), list([1])], dtype=object)
```

when I want

```
array([list([]), list([]), list([1]), list([]), list([]), list([]),
       list([]), list([]), list([]), list([])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: You have the same object at all positions

Comment: Ah. So I can't use the `.fill([])` method. Is there a way to quickly create independent lists in the empty array?

Comment: Why do you want to create an array of lists? This is less efficient than a numpy array and that a python list.

Comment: I want to have a numpy array that has different row lengths that are unknown when the array is initialized, but a known number of rows. I thought that having an array of lists would be the fastest way to append each list as the code runs since `np.append` is a slower operation than appending a list, but a list takes up more memory than a numpy array.

Comment: Better use a list of lists, a numpy array is only more efficient if you use native types, not object.

Comment: An array of lists uses about the same memory as a list of lists -  the space to store the pointers to those lists. The list can `.append` more objects.  Access to the lists is also a bit faster .About all that the array gives is things like `reshape`, and fancy indexing.